# Behaviour of open() vs os.open() when using pipes

Tags: python, named-pipes

I have been struggling with writing and reading pipes. The problem was that on one side I was treating the pipe through an file-object obtained through `open()`. And on the other side I was using a file-descriptor obtained by "low-level" `os.open()`. Although looking similar the code behaves very different and I don't really understand why.

I've made a little example. I am varying the method to write to the pipe.In **write_1.py** I use `os.open()` and erverything is working as expected. In **write_2.py** using `open()` , when reading from the pipe I get an *EAGAIN*-error and get meaningful output only when the writing side has closed using `pipe.close()` in the end.

Reading in both cases in the same way, see **read.py**.
Can you explain the different behaviour?

(Python version 3.5.2)

### Files

```py
# write_1.py
import os
import errno
import time

bufferSize = 100
PATH = "pipe"
i = 0

pipe = os.open(PATH, os.O_WRONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)

while i < 20:
    i +=1
    my_str = "written {0}-times".format(i)
    try:
        input = os.write(pipe, my_str.encode())
    except OSError as err:
        if err.errno == 11:
            print("error 11")
            continue
        else:
            raise err
    if input:
        print("written {0} chars ".format(input))
    print("Sleep 500 ms")
    time.sleep(0.5)

os.close(pipe)
```

```py
# write_2.py
import os
import errno
import time

bufferSize = 100
PATH = "pipe"
i = 0

pipe = open(PATH, "w")
fd = pipe.fileno()
fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)

while i < 20:
    i +=1
    my_str = "written {0}-times".format(i)
    try:
        input = pipe.write(my_str)
    except OSError as err:
        if err.errno == 11:
            print("error 11")
            continue
        else:
            raise err
    if input:
        print("written {0} chars ".format(input))
    print("Sleep 500 ms")
    time.sleep(0.5)

pipe.close()
```

```py
# read.py
import os
import errno
import time

bufferSize = 100
PATH = "pipe"
i = 0

pipe = os.open(PATH, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)

while i < 100:
    i +=1
    try:
        input = os.read(pipe, bufferSize)
    except OSError as err:
        if err.errno == 11:
            print("error 11")
            print("Sleep 500 ms")
            time.sleep(0.5)
            continue
        else:
            raise err
    if input:
        print(input)
    print("Sleep 500 ms")
    time.sleep(0.5)

os.close(pipe)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `open`, you have accepted the default buffering setting (by not providing a `buffering` argument), so you're getting a buffered file object. This buffer is separate from any OS-level buffering.

With `os.open`, there is no file object and no file-object-level buffering.

(Also, you opened your pipe in blocking I/O mode with `open`, but that's not the cause of the difference you're seeing.)

Comment: Sounds reasonable! Actually I was setting it to nonblocking mode, but as you say it was not making any difference. Have corrected the example.

Comment: a flush() on the file object after the write() makes the difference disappear.